# Make variable double another variable with jQuery

Tags: javascript

How can I make the value of a variable be double (or 3x, 4x, etc) that of another variable?

This doesnt work, is it just a syntax error?

```
var scrollIntervalTwo = ( 2 x scrollInterval ) ;
var scrollIntervalThree = ( 3 x scrollInterval ) ;
var scrollIntervalFour = ( 4 x scrollInterval ) ;
```

Comment: @Prasanth That should be more than enough to get the asker started!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*` instead of `x` as `x` will be seen as a string character.

Some of the basic arithmetic operators in javascript are

```
+   Addition    
-   Subtraction 
*   Multiplication   
/   Division     
%   Modulus (division remainder)    
++  Increment   
--  Decrement
```

More here http://www.javascripter.net/faq/arithmet.htm

Comment: `x` will not be seen as a "string character"...it's not enclosed in quotes. It will be interpreted as an identifier, which is most likely undefined

Answer (score 0):

To multiply, use `*` :

```
var scrollIntervalTwo =  2 * scrollInterval  ;
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)

Answer (score 0):

You are so close! Here is the modification to your code:

```
var scrollIntervalTwo = ( 2 * scrollInterval ) ;
var scrollIntervalThree = ( 3 * scrollInterval ) ;
var scrollIntervalFour = ( 4 * scrollInterval ) ;
```

Notice that the `x`'s have been changed to `*`'s.